# with jquery.dotdotdot, how do you truncate a single word when it overflows?

Tags: jquery

the following fiddle demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/inconduit/2z6Xa/

this is using jquery.dotdotdot plugin for truncating text with an ellipsis.

when there's a single word like a_really_long_filename_with_no_spaces_at_all.txt that overflows a div, this plugin does not truncate it.  is there any way to make this happen?

the html:

```
  <div id="wrapper">this_does_not_truncate_because_there_are_no_spaces</div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="wrapper2">this one has spaces and is truncated properly</div>
```

​
the javascript:

```
 $("#wrapper").dotdotdot({wrap: 'letter'});
 $("#wrapper2").dotdotdot({wrap: 'letter'});
```

the css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#wrapper2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}​
```

Comment: CSS3 has a function but since you using jQuery i think that is not good. Looks like you can report a bug. Just a simple thing in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a plugin to do this? Have you tried using the CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis`? It's supported by every single browsers except really old ones like *IE 5.5 or below* or *FF 6 or below*.

More information on `text-overflow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow

A demo page: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-ellipsis.php

Comment: show me in the fiddle how you'd get that to work? i can't get css text-overflow truncation to happen in chrome on osx.

Comment: @inconduit I have edited my answer with a demo page. Works on Chrome OSX. Not a fiddle, but you should be able to inspect it to see how it works.

Comment: @pixelfreak it might be also worth noting that as far as I can tell text-overflow truncation only seems to work on a single line of text not multiple lines?

Comment: @ak85 Yes, that is correct. inconduit, if you are looking for a multi-line ellipsis, then you'll have to resort to JS.